# How to get count of different row combinations based on multiple column values?

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

How to print out amount of different kind of product variations?

There is dropdown menu for ColumnB having values: Red,Blue,Green
There is dropdown menu for ColumnC having values: square, circle
ColumnD is count

Amount of rows can be e.g. 200 to that matter

For the example output information should be:
Red square 7
Red circle 3
Blue square 5

```
ColumnA       | ColumnB       | ColumnC       | ColumnD  
-------------------------------------------------------  
Customer name | Product color | Product shape | Count  
-------------------------------------------------------  
John Doe      | Red           | square        | 2  
John Doe      | Red           | circle        | 3  
Mary Doe      | Blue          | square        | 5  
Mary Doe      | Red           | square        | 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({B:B&" "&C:C, D:D}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) 
  where Col2 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  label sum(Col2)''"))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you player0. Can you share your try-out please? Somehow I wasn't able to get your formula working in my own sheet.

Comment: @MJo sure: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Zn9cfTMKpLFnXvF-mLgLzlNmrbinw85OYRcpr_j5u8Y/edit#gid=2064065891

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much and even more. Yes, US version and many online examples related to US version usually works but other language versions need some tinkering